# Why I can't import pandas module?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using the DAMASK software package version 3.0.0-alpha7. For the post-processing of this software we need to use the pandas module of python3.

At first, I was working with my DAMASK software, but for a specific purpose I thought that I have to change my pandas version by using the following line in a terminal:

```
pip install pandas==1.2.3
```

Let me tell you that before the running of the mentioned script, I had pandas module and I could import it easily. But now I can't import even my damask module just as similar as my pandas module and I always face with many lines of errors like these:

```
Cell In[3], line 1
----> 1 import damask
      2 import numpy as np
      3 import pandas as pd

File /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/damask/__init__.py:37
     35 from ._crystal         import Crystal          # noqa
     36 from ._orientation     import Orientation      # noqa
---> 37 from ._table           import Table            # noqa
     38 from ._colormap        import Colormap         # noqa
     39 from ._vtk             import VTK              # noqa

File /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/damask/_table.py:19
     16 import copy
     17 from typing import Union, Tuple, List, Iterable
---> 19 import pandas as pd
     20 import numpy as np
     22 from ._typehints import FileHandle

ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

another example:

```
import damask
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/damask/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from ._table           import Table            # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/damask/_table.py", line 19, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes​
```

I don't know why this happens and I would be so thankful if you could help me with my problem

Comment: Start by looking at other questions about the same error: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22source+code+string+cannot+contain+null+bytes%E2%80%8B%22+

Answer (score 0):

Undo the bad installation of Pandas like this:

```
pip uninstall pandas
```

If that also uninstalls Damask, reinstall Damask (using whatever procedure you installed it with before) and let it choose the version of Pandas.